# QWidgetAction not triggering

Tags: python, pyside2

Can someone explain to me why the 'triggered' event is not firing when i click my custom Action?

```
import os, sys
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class ActionButton(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ActionButton, self).__init__(parent)

        # controls
        self.icon = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.icon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.icon.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Sample long name')
        self.label.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

        # layout
        self.buttonLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.buttonLayout.setContentsMargins(4, 4, 4, 4)
        self.buttonLayout.setSpacing(2)
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.icon, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.buttonLayout, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


    # method
    def setText(self, value):
        self.label.setText(value)

    def setIcon(self, value):
        self.icon.setIcon(value)



class Example(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        # controls
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.toolBar)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        # custom
        wPreset = ActionButton(self)
        wAct = QtWidgets.QWidgetAction(self)
        wAct.setDefaultWidget(wPreset)
        wAct.triggered.connect(self.testThis)
        self.toolBar.addAction(wAct)

    def testThis(self):
        print('here')


def test():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    test()
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html#details): "Note that it is up to the widget to activate the action, for example by reimplementing mouse event handlers and calling QAction::trigger().". Right now your widget does nothing upon user interaction (no mouse, no keyboard), so you need to create some signal that will be emitted by `ActionButton` and connect that signal to the action's `triggered`. Can I ask you why you're adding a button that doesn't accept mouse events?

Comment: how do i connect them

Comment: Signals can be "chained": `wPreset.someSignal.connect(wAct.triggered)`. Note that signal chaining only works for compatible signatures, since `triggered` has a `bool` argument, the custom signal also need to have the same `bool` argument. Note that in this case you can also connect to the `trigger()` slot of QAction, but remember that this will cause toggling the action state if it's checkable and eventually switch the action group (if any, and if it's exclusive).